# Authentication fail when connecting to Atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-atlas, mlab

I have an error when connecting to the MongoDB Atlas database after I migrated the data from the old MLAB.

I have definitely setup the username and password correctly as in the documentation (obviously i replaced PASSWORD with my correct MLAB password:

```
var mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://heroku_3kcdl3j9:PASSWORD@cluster-3kcdl3j9.auof1.mongodb.net/heroku_3kcdl3j9?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

I have migrated my database from MLAB to Atlas successfully set the correct Network access settings to 0.0.0.0 IP address. Setup the environment variable in Heroku.

I connect to the atlas database with this code, do I need some special options? (this code works with the old MLAB connection)

```
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, 
  // { config: { autoIndex: true } }, 
  // { options : { ssl: true } }, 
  function (error) {
    if (error) console.error(error);
    else console.log('mongo connected');

     const con = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db)
        con.buildInfo( (err, mongoURI) => {
        if(err){
          throw err
        }
       // see the db version
        // console.log('mongo db.version():  '+ db.version);
      })
});
```

However, I still get this error, I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
    { MongoError: authentication fail
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1462:15
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:868:7
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:844:20
    at finish (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:232:16)
    at handleEnd (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:242:7)
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:351:15
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:531:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'authentication fail',
  errors:
   [ { name: 'cluster-3kcdl3j9-shard-00-01.auof1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] },
     { name: 'cluster-3kcdl3j9-shard-00-00.auof1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] },
     { name: 'cluster-3kcdl3j9-shard-00-02.auof1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] } ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:47015) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined
    at Admin.buildInfo (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:100:37)
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/index.js:95:13
    at $initialConnection.then.err (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:556:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:47015) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:47015) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:47015) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: authentication fail
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1462:15
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:868:7
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:844:20
    at finish (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:232:16)
    at handleEnd (/Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:242:7)
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:351:15
    at /Users/bensmith/Downloads/DocumentsDirNew/Scraper and API/diveapi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:531:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:47015) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Your credentials are wrong or not properly escaped, or the user does not exist. Read server log to see what it thinks of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

On the migration documentation from MLAB to ATLAS I can read:

Atlas servers always run with requireSSL and only accept TLS/SSL encrypted connections.

I can see that your ssl option is commented.
This is one problem.

Comment: I have tried with this option and it didn't make any difference... also changed the way I am connecting now to use the MongoClient as it says on Atlas, this hasn't fixed it eitther, i am totally stuck: const client = new MongoClient(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, { options : { ssl: true } });
client.connect(err => {

Answer (score 0):

The problem was it was something to do with the username and password. I believe there was an illegal character in the password. So I created another user with a better password and the server authenticated and logged in allowing it to connect.